# What is the intuition behind Kontsevich-Iyudu-Shkarin result?

Tags: matrices

According to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1965), a cube of a composition of matrix inverse, matrix elements' inverse, and matrix transposition modifies 3x3 matrix by multiplying on left and right side by diagonal matrices.

A square of such composition is identity for 2x2 matrices over a commutative ring because in 2x2 case these operation commute and each squares to identity.

Therefore the questions:

What are the intuitive reasons why the 3x3 case it true?

Specifically, why ones need to cube a composition of order 2 elements to get something resembling an identity?

Comment: Can you write out what you mean in symbols in addition to words?  That would make it easier for me (and I'd guess others) to follow.

Comment: @NoahStein: The abstract of the link in the question has concise explanation in symbols: http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is contained in [Kontsevich's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2469) (where he conjectures this result).